# Knockout refresh observableArray in the html

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova, knockout.js

I'm working on Android with Jquery Mobile with PhoneGap using Knockout for loading data.

I'm getting the data all right and loading it on the HTML page accordingly to the for each data-bind I have on the tags.

When I want to refresh the data, it just doesn't do it. It returns just an HTML without bound data or throwing dom exception not found.

My applyBinding happens inside pagecreate event of the page.

I've posted a simple example describing the problem on my SkyDrive - http://sdrv.ms/LpUdLt
It's a public example reproducing the problem.
the viewmodel holds an array that holds array.
refreshed with randomal values.
trying to reload the page in jquery mobile with changepage reload with new data by pressing the navbar button fails with the dom object mistake. 
I do agree not to that I shouldn't create an instance of VM every page create, just can't find a way to implement it, so that the data will be rerendered on HTML.

```
   //indexPage.js
   var wAViewModelInst ;
   var viewPageIndexContent;
   $('#pageIndex').live('pagecreate', function (event) { 
        viewPageIndexContent = document.getElementById("pageIndexContent");
        wAViewModelInst = new WAViewModel(true);
        ko.applyBindings(wAViewModelInst, viewPageIndexContent);

        waHeaderVM.refreshContentData = function () {

              // wAViewModelInst.updateRowList();
              // ko.cleanNode(viewPageIndexContent);
              // viewPageIndexContent = document.getElementById("pageIndexContent");
              //wAViewModelInst = new WAViewModel(true);
             //ko.applyBindings(wAViewModelInst, viewPageIndexContent);
              $.mobile.changePage("index.html", { allowSamePageTransition: true, reloadPage: true });
              $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();
       }
   }

    //WAViewModel
    self.WARowList = ko.observableArray();
    self.updateRowList = function () {
        self.WARowList(self.GetWA());
    }
    //tried the exteding 
    //ko.observableArray.fn.WARowListUpdate = function () {
    //    //create a sub-observable
    //    this.hasItems = ko.observable();

    //    //update it when the observableArray is updated
    //    this.subscribe(function (newValue) {
    //        this.hasItems(newValue && newValue.length ? true : false);
    //    }, this);

    //    //trigger change to initialize the value
    //    this.valueHasMutated();

    //    //support chaining by returning the array
    //    return this;
    //};
```

is there any way to update the html after the first rendering ?

adding the html code:

```
<div id="pageIndex" data-role="page" data-transition="flip" data-theme="e" data-dom-cache="true">
    <div id="indexHeader" data-role="header" data-theme="e">
        <div data-role="navbar" data-iconpos="right">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="login.html" data-role="tab" data-icon="back" data-bind="click: loadingHandler"
                    class="brighter-text">חזרה</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" data-role="tab" data-icon="refresh" data-bind ="click: refreshContentData" >רענן</a></li>
                <li><a href="researchEvent.html" data-role="tab" data-icon="check" id="navBarResearchEventPage"   data-bind="click: loadResearchEvent" class="brighter-text">ביצוע חקר</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" data-role="tab" data-icon="grid" class="ui-btn-active brighter-text">
                    סידור עבודה</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="pageIndexContent" data-role="content" data-theme="e" style="padding-bottom: 52px;
        height: 570px;">
        <h2 data-bind="text:Title" class="brighter-text" style="font-size:22pt;">
        </h2>
        <div data-bind="foreach: WARowList" style="width: 99%; text-align: center">
            <div>
                <table style="float: right; width: 20%; height: 60px;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                    <tr data-bind="visible : FirstRow " style="height: 31px;">
                        <th class="AlignedHeader">
                            <label>
                                שעה / שילוט</label>
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr data-bind="style: { backgroundColor: Odd() ? '#8CC63F' : '#AFC493' }">
                        <td style="width: 20%;" data-bind="style: { backgroundColor: IsNew() ? 'yellow' : 'transparent' }">
                            <input  type="button" data-bind="click: ShowSampleDetails, value: ShilutTime , jQueryButtonUIEnableDisable:$data"
                                data-icon="plus" data-iconpos="right"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <table style="height: 60px; width: 80%; background-color: #8CC63F;" data-bind="style: { backgroundColor: Odd() ? '#8CC63F' : '#AFC493' }"
                    cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                    <thead data-bind="if : FirstRow">
                        <tr data-bind="foreach: CellList">
                            <th class="AlignedHeader">
                                <label data-bind="text: Date">
                                </label>
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr data-bind="foreach: CellList">
                            <td style="width: 11.5%;">
                                <div data-bind="visible:IsPopulated ">
                                    <div data-bind="visible: HasDrivers">
                                        <input type="button" data-role="button" data-bind="click: ShowBusDriverList.bind($data , $root) , jQueryButtonUIEnableDisable: $data "
                                            data-icon="search" data-iconpos="right" value="נהגים" class="brighter-text" />
                                    </div>
                                    <div data-bind="visible: !HasDrivers()">
                                        <input type="button" data-role="button" id="btnNoDriver" disabled="disabled" data-icon="info"
                                            data-iconpos="right" value="אין נהג" class="brighter-text" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div data-bind="visible: !IsPopulated">
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
```

and so on ..

the GetWA function returns an observableArray of warow list .
it works the first time the trouble is rerendering the dom object.
the dom element is contaminated with ko and fails ..

I tried the answer of Luffy :

```
var lVM = new loginViewModel();
var  footerViewModelLogin = {
        IsOnline: ko.observable(globalContext.Network()),
        IsSync: ko.observable(globalContext.Sync())
    };
$('#login').live('pagecreate', function (event) {


     viewLoginContent = document.getElementById("loginContent");

    ko.applyBindingsToNode(viewLoginContent, lVM);


    viewLoginFooter= document.getElementById("footerLogin");

    ko.applyBindingsToNode(viewLoginFooter, footerViewModelLogin);


});


$('#login').live('pagehide', function (event, ui) {
    $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();

});



function loginViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    try {

        self.userName = ko.observable("");
        self.password = ko.observable("");
        self.message = ko.observable("");

        self.CleanGlobalContext = function () {
          ...

        };

        self.Validate = function () {

            ...

        };
    }
    catch (e) {
        if (IsDebug) alert("GlobalContext.prototype.SetMapOverlay  " + e.message);
        if (typeof (console) != 'undefined' && console) console.log("GlobalContext.prototype.SetMapOverlay "     + e.message);
    }
}

ko.applyBindings(lVM);
ko.applyBindings(footerViewModelLogin);
```

The knockout fails without the element predefined event to bind .

Comment: Can you show us a little more code, such as the HTML, or the GetWA method?  When you say 'it returns just empty HTML', what is being called that returns the empty HTML?

Comment: the question is there a way to reapply the bindings ? 
the reinitialize of the observabeArray in the viewModel doesn't reorganize and repaint the view.

Comment: i've corrected the post - it doesn't return emty html - it returns an html without the data-bind information of the refreshed viewmodel.

Comment: I've added a simple reproducing problem example . Please advise ..

Comment: I found your example solution a little hard to follow. In your code above I'm confused by the lines in the commented out section where you recreate a new WAViewModel and reapply bindings. If GetWA() returns JSON data for new rows, don't you want to just update the observable array with this data? Why recreate the parent WAViewModel? Or am I misunderstanding the view model structure?

Comment: I don't want to recreate the WAViewModel. That's the point. I only want to enter new data in a complex observableArray type - WARowList. When I only update the observableArray by the function GetWA inside the WAViewModel , it doesn't reapear with the new data on the page.
So the lifecycle is -> pagecreate for the first time -> set the new instance of viewmodel -> apply to ko and show on html -> reload the page with changepage of jqm -> enter new data in viewmodel(in observable array) -> reapply the html binding.

Comment: the last part fails(the reapply/rerender) if i don't recreate the viewmodel from zero. the html does show the mark up but without any bindings .

Comment: the GetWA - goes to wcf returns json (it's all good and checked) then inside initializes the rows that each has it's own cells with their own data . It returns already an ovservableArray built up and ready for usage , not Json as you suggested before.

Comment: @Gregory, is there anyway you can simplify this down, its hard to understand exactly what you are after with so much extra code.

Answer (score 2):

I have not understood well you difficulty. However, I don't understand why you need to reapply bindings. Notice what follows:

1. If you change an observable array the needed templates are re-instantiated to updated coherently the UI. However you have to update the observalble array either by using the observable array functions, or by passing to the observable a new array: obs(newArray).
2. If you need to perform actions after the ko re-rendering you just need to use the afterRender, or afterAdd parameters of the template binding
3. if you add new jquery mobile code you have to parse it after having created it otherwise jquery mobile will not work...again you can do this in the afterRender function.
4. it is problematic to load html containing ajax ko bindings via ajax. The right approach is to create that content as a template, that you render immediately (not with ajax). Then you query the server just to get new json content. Then you can instantiate the template by using for instance the with binding.

Comment: 1.I reinited the observable array with new data , but the needed templates are not re-instantiated to updated coherently the UI. actualy it just shows me the html without data at all .
2.afterRender I need to create update bindingHandler for the observable Array ?
3.each time i navigate between the jqm pages , after the first applyBinding the dom "element" can't be reinitialized . thats the problem.

Comment: maybe there is some error somewhere...I use a lot templates ...an I never had a similar problem...however when I use jquery mobile with knockout I preload all pages and I communicate with the server just in json...I downloaded your code...let me give a look.

Comment: preload would be the best option if i could refresh the ko data in it.

Comment: do you have some sample of 4 paragraph of your response? all my transfer to wcf is through ajax requests by functions that are called in different processes of the application .

Comment: YOU CAN! To do so you need to put the content of your page (just the content not the div with the page name) within a "with" knockout construct. Tis way when you change the data the with is bound to the content is re-initialized. obviously in the afterRender event you have to trigger a jquery mobile parsing of the new content

Comment: about the sample...the point is that I use mvc helpers I have written...so I dont call directly knockout functions. I have a complete framework...that do a lot of job automatically such as parsing of new content for adding validation, and for initializing 3d party controls (such as the ones of jquery mobile)...However, if you read about the with statement the implementation should be easy. If you want to use my framework it is contained in my Mvc Controls Toolkit...but you have to study a lot...so I dont think it is a good idea in your case.

Comment: so I must change the foreach binding for with , and implement afterRender ?

Comment: if you preload all your pages you don't get to go through the pagecreate to reapply bindings per element .
where do you refresh the data ? 
scenario 1 - user enters app(login page) ,redirects to the second page and by the username gets the table filled .now , he goes back to the first page (login) and enters new username . at the pagecreate i update the rows in the viewmodel and re apply binding from zero . 
that all can be done only because when i pagehide the second page(when he returns to the login page) i remove it programatically from dom object , and then

Comment: from the first page(the login) i do $mobile.changePage with reload for the second page - that brings me to pagecreate . 
scenario 2 - no solution yet , every half an hour refresh the data of the list on the second page .

Comment: 1) Ho do I refresh pages? in knockout page are refreshed by simply changing the viewmodel bound to the pages. If thewhole content oa a page is contained within a knockout with statement bound say to an object contained in prop1 of the View mode...you need just to do: prop1(null); prop1(newData)...and thhe whole content is refreshed. You must do this before changing page then you trigger the page change.

Comment: 2) I think that your current approach doesnt work because you apply binding before the page is ready. You have to apply bindings not immediately after having loaded the page through ajas but on the load complete event (try fidderent events to get the right timing between jquerymobile initialization and knockout initialization). In any case this pproach is difficult before you need to tune exactly the sequence of vents (knockout and mobile widjets initializatio):
a) page loaded succesfully b) apply bindins c) initilaiza mobile widjets...this should be the right sequence.

Comment: what do you mean : you need just to do: prop1(null); prop1(newData)
do you have some kind of a simple sample of your structure ?
I'm working with Mvc as a backoffice so i not to afraid of your framework you were talking about . :) Did you have a look at the repro I've posted? I've added the updateRows function as an afterRender implementation in the data binding , but now it refreshes all the time.. still working on it.. ajax is async in this case..

Comment: I have seen your code, but I dont understand all details. in your current approach ny approach 2, you mainly need to change the events you works with. I know ajax is asynch...but jQuery mobile uses events to say you when the page is available on the server...on that event you cab call applyBinding. Approach 1 works in a completely different way:

Comment: 1) you have an overall ViewModel containing all pages ViewModels. Let call it totalModel. Then your page1VM is contained on a property of this ViewModel: totalViewModel.p1   for instance. Now to refresh your page you need just to do totalPage.p1(new page1VM())...THis will put new fresh data in the total ViewModel. Now if p1 property is bound to a ko with statement the html of the page is recomputed automatically by ko. on the afterRender of the with statement you parse the content of the page to make all jquery mobile gadgets work. apply the with statemen only to the internal content of the pg

Comment: hmm.. ok . that's a bit to abstract for me , even though I do understand the direction. got some simple sample to copycat a bit from ? :)  the TotalView would be some global parameter , I assume . 
How do you navigate between the pages? with an usual changePage of jqm ?  
The trouble is that I have two very complicated VM's .. It would be a pain to unite it.. 
fyi : The after render worked for me only if the ajax call was synchronous

Comment: You do not need to unite the two pages viewmodels, just put them as they are as two different observable properties of an overall ViewMode. Each time you change page you can create new page1 or aq new page2 and then put them in its observable property of the overall ViewModel. Yes I change page by manually calling the changePage function. Now if pages are preloaded there are no time critical event: you create a new page model put it in its property of the overall viewmodel, parse the newly created html to initilalize all jqm widjets and then you change page by calling changePage

Comment: hi , I thought that the solution was to use the afterRender that you suggested . nevertheless . i've removed the afterRender and the app updates itself.
The issue was disposing of the values in the existed list and re initializing the values with new data .
sorry for removing the acceptance of the answer - it's just not the solution that was needed.

Comment: when bindings are applied they need to be disposed if you wan reuse that html and attach new bindings. However, the usual way to use the same markup with different data is by using templates, in which case all housekeeping job is done automatically by knockout. Since in this case you have a single item to show, the simplest way to do this is by using the "with" binding. If you are interested in susing extensively knockout, please give a look to the with documentation: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/with-binding.html
There there are also examples that may help you its pratical usage.

Comment: The afterRender is not intended for enabling knockout to work properly but just for initializing the jquery mobile widjet on newly created Html added to the dom. After you create a some html nodes, containing say a select...then by calling in the afterRender the jquery mobile parsing function you enhance that select, and also other html nodes into the jquery mobile widjets shown in the jquery mobile web site...otherwise the select and also all other html will look as a normal select without the look and enhancements of jquery mobile.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can reapply bindings with ko.applyBindingsToNode function to the specific dom element.

> > Check these examples
>
> 1. http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/gYk6f/  ---> With templating
> 2. http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/BnDh6/  ---> With data - value pair

Comment: I"ll try it . but the problem that it's an observableArray with nested observableArrays. is it the same ?

Comment: It didn't got through the apply binding without defined element

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to add afterRender on the foreach table data-bind. as – Francesco Abbruzzese suggested. 
The ajax request has been turned to async:false though. 
Each time I update the list I perform some dat-bind = "click:updateRowList" which updates the table. 
Thanks a lot to Elad Katz for help with bounty .

Comment: hi , I thought that the solution was to use the afterRender that you suggested . nevertheless . i've removed the afterRender and the app updates itself.
The issue was disposing of the values in the existed list and re initializing the values with new data .